# Attempted to call function "imap_open" from namespace

Tags: symfony, console, imap, php-5.6

I created a Symfony command that parses an IMAP mailbox.
The IMAP extension is installed and enabled.

When I execute the command I have this error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedFunctionException]
  Attempted to call function "imap_open" from namespace "CAB\MainBundle\Imap".
```

But through the browser, I haven't this error and the `imap_open` is executed without error.

Why the `imap_open` doesn't exist when it is executed from the console?

Comment: Check your php cli configuration, it looks like the extension is not enabled for cli.

Comment: The extension was enabled for both apache and CLI : _extension=imap.so_ in /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-imap.ini

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the server, there are two PHP versions installed : **PHP5.6 and PHP7**. The *IMAP* extension is enabled in **PHP 5.6** but it is not enabled for **PHP 7**.
So when I run the command with `php app/console parse:mailbox` it calls the **PHP7** and since the imap extension isn't enabled for **PHP7** the code throws an `UndefinedFunctionException` exception

The right way is to execute the command with php5.6

```
php5.6 app/console parse:mailbox
```